# Reordering columns in data frame once again

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I want to re-order my columns in my data frame, but what I found so far is not satisfactory.

My dataframe looks like:

```
cnt  <-as.factor(c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3" ))
bnk  <-as.factor(c("bank 1", "bank 2", "bank 3", "bank 1", "bank 2", "bank 3" ))
mayData <-data.frame(age=c(10,12,13,10,11,15), Country=cnt, Bank=bnk, q10=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),q11=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), q1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), q9=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), q6=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), year=c(1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000) )

   age    Country     Bank  q10 q11 q1  q9  q6  year
1   10  Country 1   bank 1  1   1   1   1   1   1950
2   12  Country 2   bank 2  1   1   1   1   1   1960
3   13  Country 3   bank 3  1   1   1   1   1   1970
4   10  Country 1   bank 1  2   2   2   2   2   1980
5   11  Country 2   bank 2  2   2   2   2   2   1990
6   15  Country 3   bank 3  2   2   2   2   2   2000
```

but I want to re-arrange the columns to look like this:

```
      Country     Bank  year    age q1  q6  q9  q10 q11
1   Country 1   bank 1  1950    10  1   1   1   1   1
2   Country 2   bank 2  1960    12  1   1   1   1   1
3   Country 3   bank 3  1970    13  1   1   1   1   1
4   Country 1   bank 1  1980    10  2   2   2   2   2
5   Country 2   bank 2  1990    11  2   2   2   2   2
6   Country 3   bank 3  2000    15  2   2   2   2   2
```

My real dataframe has a lot of columns, so rearranging the column orders "manually" using the index or the names of each column is not optimal.

Notice also, that for the column names that begin with `q`s I want to have them in ascending order, that is from `q1` to `q11`. The problem is that R fails to understand that `q6` - which stands for "question 6" - should be precede `q10`. To see this deficiency, look at the following example:

```
mayData<-mayData[,order(colnames(mayData),decreasing=F)] 

    age   Bank    Country   q1  q10 q11 q6  q9  year
1   10  bank 1  Country 1   1   1   1   1   1   1950
2   12  bank 2  Country 2   1   1   1   1   1   1960
3   13  bank 3  Country 3   1   1   1   1   1   1970
4   10  bank 1  Country 1   2   2   2   2   2   1980
5   11  bank 2  Country 2   2   2   2   2   2   1990
6   15  bank 3  Country 3   2   2   2   2   2   2000
```

So, essentially the way I want to reorder my columns is to first sort a few columns in some flexible way according to my preference and then use a decreasing ordering criteria. But, the "logical" one, one that R can understand to sort the `q`s properly.

Comment: try `q01`, `q06` and `q09` instead.

Comment: you can order your `q..` columns based on `as.numeric(sub("^q", "", colnames(...)))` (and you can spot those columns with something like `grep("^q", colnames(mayData))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mixedsort` from `gtools` to arrange the 'q' columns.

```
library(gtools)
i1 <- grep("q\\d+", names(mayData))
nm1 <- mixedsort(names(mayData)[i1])
mayData[c(setdiff(names(mayData), nm1), nm1)]
#  age   Country   Bank year q1 q6 q9 q10 q11
#1  10 Country 1 bank 1 1950  1  1  1   1   1
#2  12 Country 2 bank 2 1960  1  1  1   1   1
#3  13 Country 3 bank 3 1970  1  1  1   1   1
#4  10 Country 1 bank 1 1980  2  2  2   2   2
#5  11 Country 2 bank 2 1990  2  2  2   2   2
#6  15 Country 3 bank 3 2000  2  2  2   2   2
```

NOTE: Using only `base R` functions and a single package.

Or as @Cath mentioned, removing the substring with `gsub` can be used to order as well

```
sort(as.numeric(sub("^q", "", names(mayData)[i1])))
```

Comment: and you can even avoid the loading of `gtools` with `sort(as.numeric(sub("^q", "", names(mayData)[i1])))` ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but can again the sorting is not complete as it misses the way that I want to re-arrange the other columns. Unless you don't have some other interesting suggestion, I believe I can handle this my own combining the other responses here.

Comment: @msh855 It is the expected output you showed in your post.  The other columns `Country     Bank  year    age` doesn't follow the alphabetic order.  So, i am not sure what kind of pattern you want to order

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the column names with a single digit to add a leading zero:

```
cn <- names(mayData)
q_digit <- cn[grep("^q[0-9]$", cn)]
names(mayData)[names(mayData) %in% q_digit] <- gsub("q", "q0", q_digit)
mayData[,order(colnames(mayData),decreasing=F)] 

mayData    
age   Bank   Country   q01 q06 q09 q10 q11 year
1  10 bank 1 Country 1   1   1   1   1   1 1950
2  12 bank 2 Country 2   1   1   1   1   1 1960
3  13 bank 3 Country 3   1   1   1   1   1 1970
4  10 bank 1 Country 1   2   2   2   2   2 1980
5  11 bank 2 Country 2   2   2   2   2   2 1990
6  15 bank 3 Country 3   2   2   2   2   2 2000
```

This supposes you have less than 100 questions, if you have more you can adapt this to add another zeros to the double-digits column names.

Comment: Thanks, this might solve the sorting of q's, but how I can combine to also rearrange the other columns such as ultimately to get the second table that I can in my question. Do, you suggest to this "manually" after this step ?

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't see this part. Look at alistaire's answer, it is much better than mine and covers this.

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging `dplyr`'s `select` and `num_range` and `tidyr::extract_numeric`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mayData %>% select(Country, Bank, year, age, 
                   num_range('q', sort(extract_numeric(names(mayData)))))
#     Country   Bank year age q1 q6 q9 q10 q11
# 1 Country 1 bank 1 1950  10  1  1  1   1   1
# 2 Country 2 bank 2 1960  12  1  1  1   1   1
# 3 Country 3 bank 3 1970  13  1  1  1   1   1
# 4 Country 1 bank 1 1980  10  2  2  2   2   2
# 5 Country 2 bank 2 1990  11  2  2  2   2   2
# 6 Country 3 bank 3 2000  15  2  2  2   2   2
```