# A handy means of reordering columns in large data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe

This question pertains to reordering of columns in a large data frame, for example, having about 800 columns. The data frame has many column names preceding different dates for each id (i.e. first column). Similar questions appear online (e.g. [Reordering columns in data frame once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296162/reordering-columns-in-data-frame-once-again) and [Reordering columns in large data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583111/reordering-columns-in-large-data-frame)) but their specifics do not fit into my case. A sample of the data set is

```
df <-
structure(
list(
  id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L),
  date1 = c("1/4/2004", "3/8/2004", "NA", "13/10/2004","11/3/2003"),
  ax=c(1,2,1,"NA",5),
  am=c(1,0,1,0,0),
  aq=c(0,0,1,1,1),
  date2 = c("8/6/2002", "11/5/2004", "3/5/2004", 
"25/11/2004","21/1/2004"),
  bx=c(3,2,6,1,5),
  bm=c(1,1,0,1,1),
  bq=c(1,0,1,0,0),
  date3=c("23/6/2006", "24/12/2006", "18/2/2006", "NA","NA"),
  cx=c(1,2,4,1,0),
  cm=c(1,1,0,1,1),
  cq=c(1,0,1,0,0)
 ),
.Names = c("id", 
"date1","ax","am","aq","date2","bx","bm","bq","date3","cx","cm","cq"),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-5L)
)
```

I want to reorder the columns such that we have "am","aq","ax"; "bm","bq","bx" and "cm","cq","cx" following the date1; date2 and date3, respectively. For this small scenario example, I have tried

```
df1<-df[,c(1,2,4,5,3,6,8,9,7,10,12,13,11)]
```

This code works well and it produces the expected results below

```
df1
  id      date1 am aq ax      date2 bm bq bx      date3 cm cq cx
1  1   1/4/2004  1  0  1   8/6/2002  1  1  3  23/6/2006  1  1  1
2  2   3/8/2004  0  0  2  11/5/2004  1  0  2 24/12/2006  1  0  2
3  3         NA  1  1  1   3/5/2004  0  1  6  18/2/2006  0  1  4
4  4 13/10/2004  0  1 NA 25/11/2004  1  0  1         NA  1  0  1
5  5  11/3/2003  0  1  5  21/1/2004  1  0  5         NA  1  0  0
```

However, I am looking for a much handy code that would be easy on large data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your complete data follows the pattern you've outlined you can recycle a vector of position adjustments like so:

```
df[c(1, (2:ncol(df) + c(0,1,1,-2)))]

  id      date1 am aq ax      date2 bm bq bx      date3 cm cq cx
1  1   1/4/2004  1  0  1   8/6/2002  1  1  3  23/6/2006  1  1  1
2  2   3/8/2004  0  0  2  11/5/2004  1  0  2 24/12/2006  1  0  2
3  3         NA  1  1  1   3/5/2004  0  1  6  18/2/2006  0  1  4
4  4 13/10/2004  0  1 NA 25/11/2004  1  0  1         NA  1  0  1
5  5  11/3/2003  0  1  5  21/1/2004  1  0  5         NA  1  0  0
```

Explanation:

The pattern is to keep the date in place, move second and third columns forward one, and move the fourth back two.  We can create a vector of this:

```
adj.pattern <- c(0,1,1,-2)
```

Because R recycles shorter vectors to match the length of longer ones we can apply it easily to the index of column positions from position 2 to the number of columns in the data frame `2:ncol(df)`, which gives

```
col.index <- 2:ncol(df) + adj.pattern
col.index

[1]  2  4  5  3  6  8  9  7 10 12 13 11
```

Then we use this index to order the data frame (adding `1` at the start for the ID column):

```
df[c(1, col.index)]
```

Comment: @H 1 your code works well for the example data above. If I get the understanding I would be able to extend it to handle the complete data. Could you please give an explanation to it. Thank you!

Comment: @TRichard - added an explanation for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `id` and `date` columns fixed and `sort` the remaining columns within themselves based on name, we can do

```
#1:ncol(df)
all_cols <- seq_len(ncol(df))
#Get indices of fixed columns
fixed_columns <- c(1, grep("date", names(df)))
#Get the name of columns apart from fixed ones
cols <- names(df)[-fixed_columns]
#Sort and match them and update the new order in all_cols
all_cols[-fixed_columns] <- match(sort(cols), names(df))
df[all_cols]

#  id      date1 am aq ax      date2 bm bq bx      date3 cm cq cx
#1  1   1/4/2004  1  0  1   8/6/2002  1  1  3  23/6/2006  1  1  1
#2  2   3/8/2004  0  0  2  11/5/2004  1  0  2 24/12/2006  1  0  2
#3  3         NA  1  1  1   3/5/2004  0  1  6  18/2/2006  0  1  4
#4  4 13/10/2004  0  1 NA 25/11/2004  1  0  1         NA  1  0  1
#5  5  11/3/2003  0  1  5  21/1/2004  1  0  5         NA  1  0  0
```